# Why not have a code snippet feature for SQL in the question/answer like the one for JavaScript, CSS, and HTML?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

I am just wondering why can't we have a code snippet feature for SQL just like the `sqlFiddle`?

We already have a jsFiddle-like snippet editor for live demo/code. This way SQL code can be included in the answer/question with a live demo. And FYI, we have [43K+ posts with a link to sqlFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fsqlfiddle.com%2A%22). So is it not a good idea to include a quick code snippet option for SQL?

Comment: What database should people's SQL demo code run in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because jsFiddle is really something easy to set up unlike sqlFiddle. It's pretty much some javascript running in a sandbox.

SQLFiddle require to have the said databases running in the background. This is something really heavier, and so probably not worth. I'm pretty sure that the 90%+ answers on SQL are answers that contains pretty simple query. Addind an SQLFiddle in a complex answer where you have to setup the schema, the data and the query will probably go far further than 30k character.

So either :

- The query is really short and easy to test.
- The query is too complex and the fiddle just won't fit in here.

For information : there is about 12M question on SO, 1.1M question tagged javascript while there is 330K questions tagged SQL, not saying anything about it, just wanted to shows the number for those who are interested.

Finally, we could think about some emulation that interpret SQL but it just won't fit, there is too often differences between databases to have something reliable.

<s>PS : where do we get the total questions posted on SO by the way ?</s>

Thanks to Fabio Poloni we can said know that there is 12M question on SO : https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/505420/total-questions

Comment: I guess there's a statistic, but anyway I did this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/505420/total-questions