# Support running snippets in languages other than just JavaScript

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

From the [Snippets Announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

> ## Why?
>
> Every question is better for having minimal, reproducible code.
>
> ...
>
> Similarly, answers that include runnable code are easier to use and understand, because you can try them out

I see this question has been asked for specific [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326986/why-not-have-a-code-snippet-feature-for-sql-in-the-question-answer-like-the-one) languages suggesting [specific](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323179/please-can-we-have-runnable-python-snippets-using-skulpt) [solutions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275350/use-repl-it-to-add-snippets-for-more-languages).

It seems like it would be nice to support running code from languages other than JavaScript in snippets.

Various other online sites support C++, Haskell, Lua, Ocaml, Perl, Python, Ruby, Scheme, Java, etc...

Or as a start even just other JavaScript transpilers. Babel is in there now for ES6. How about Typescript, Flow, Clojurescript, etc..

Comment: This was asked before and decilned.  I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Wait, you've seen this question asked for specific languages, and so decided to add one for all languages?  Even though in order to support this, each language would have to be handled different?  Wut?

Comment: You forgot [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: I'd like to have a snippet runner for [tag:malbolge] please. Can we have that pleaaaaase, is think it's extremely important for questions about that language.

Comment: @Will, they've already added babel support which means they're already doing translation of the text. No reason to stop there. The reasons snippets were added in the first place are listed at the top of the question. If those reasons don't apply to other languages then they also don't apply to JavaScript and snippets should be removed. Otherwise other languages should be supported for the same reasons.

Comment: @gman but... each one would have to be handled separately, as they're different languages.  And they would have to be prioritized.  And, at some point, you have to stop adding language support.  A general question is useless for these reasons.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Stack Snippets for PowerShell, Python, etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329030/289905).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You still want malbolge? https://tio.run/#malbolge ;)

Answer (score 8):

[As I said before (for Python specifically)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323889/6083675), you could use the currently available features within Stack Snippets to get something similar:

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/Caky/1.js"></script>
```

Of course, you should never just leave it at that. You need to provide the real code, not just a link. This is Ruby:

```ruby
print "World, hello!"

a = [ 45, 3, 19, 8 ]
b = [ 'sam', 'max', 56, 98.9, 3, 10, 'jill' ]
print (a + b).join(' '), "\n"
print a[2], " ", b[4], " ", b[-2], "\n"
print a.sort.join(' '), "\n"
a << 57 << 9 << 'phil'
print "A: ", a.join(' '), "\n"

b << 'alex' << 48 << 220
print "B: ", b.join(' '), "\n"
print "pop: ", b.pop, "\n"
print "shift: ", b.shift, "\n"
print "C: ", b.join(' '), "\n"

b.delete_at(2)
b.delete('alex')
print "D: ", b.join(' '), "\n"
```

---

Now, before you say "but I want to force them to make an MVCE", let me tell you that this will not work as a solution. They will find a way to screw it up:

```
print "https://repl.it/Caky/1"
```

Half the time when a new user uses the feature as it is, the snippet is actually a *Java* snippet. Or it fails to compile. Or it compiles, but nothing shows up.

JS/HTML/CSS are native to the browser, so our current system easily accommodates them. Most, if not all of these other online testers fail to work with anything graphical, which was one of the biggest advantages of Stack Snippets in the first place.

In the end, this trick is really only useful for answerers who want an edge. I wouldn't overdo it, as I personally feel this has the potential to become a broken link or a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 8):

Well, just a few thoughts:

- How would you address compiler specific behavior coming along with tags like [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) or [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc)?
- It's already possible to post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)'s and refer to appropriate [Online IDE's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) as listed from tag wiki's.
- Snippets are annoyingly used already, where they simply don't apply, wrong programming language or not.

I don't think it's necessary/wanted to add runnable code snippets support for more languages.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Lua can be supported by using [Fengari](https://fengari.io), a Lua VM implemented in JS.

So taking Laurel's Ruby snippet example and turning it into Lua:

```html
<script src="//github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>

<script type="application/lua">
local table = require 'table'

table.add = function(a, b)
  local c = {}
  for _, v in ipairs(a) do c[#c + 1] = v end
  for _, v in ipairs(b) do c[#c + 1] = v end
  return c
end

table.find = function(t, key)
  for i, value in ipairs(t) do
    if key == value then return i end
  end
  return nil
end

print "World, hello!"

a = { 45, 3, 19, 8 }
b = { 'sam', 'max', 56, 98.9, 3, 10, 'jill' }

print ( table.concat(table.add(a, b), ' '), "\n" )
print (a[2], b[4], b[#b - 2], "\n")
table.sort(a)
print (table.concat(a, ' '), "\n")

table.insert(a, 57)
table.insert(a, 9)
table.insert(a, 'phil')
print ("A: ", table.concat(a, ' '), "\n")

table.insert(b, 'alex')
table.insert(b, 48)
table.insert(b, 200)
print ("B: ", table.concat(b, ' '), "\n")
print ("pop: ", table.remove(b), "\n")
print ("shift: ", table.remove(b, 1), "\n")
print ("C: ", table.concat(b, ' '), "\n")

table.remove(b, 2)
table.remove(b, table.find(b, 'alex'))
print ("D: ", table.concat(b, ' '), "\n")

print "Fengari enables Lua!!"
</script>
```

This is great. Got one of my favorite scripting languages working with SO snippets :)